# Why doesn't this Haskell code exhaust the heap?

Tags: haskell, memory-leaks

This code sums the contents of two (mutually cancelling) infinite lists specified at the top level:

```
{-# language BangPatterns #-}
module Main where

unending1 :: [Int]
unending1 = cycle [1]

unending2 :: [Int]
unending2 = cycle [negate 1]

main :: IO ()
main = do
    let summator :: Int -> [Int] -> [Int] -> Int
        summator !acc (i1 : rest1) (i2 : rest2) =
            if acc > 100
            then acc -- never happens
            else summator (acc+i1+i2) rest1 rest2
    print (summator 0 unending1 unending2)
```

I compile this code with no optimizations and a low heap size, like this:

```
ghc -O0 -with-rtsopts="-M10m" Main.hs
```

My intuition is that this code would cause a memory leak, because the summation function would try to "materialize" the two lists, and the heads of both of them are at the top-level, so they won't be discarded.

However when I execute the program it seems to run indefinitely without problems.

Where am I mistaken?

---

**Edit.** Inspecting the generated Core using `-ddump-simpl`, the lists seem to remain at the top level. For example:

```
Result size of Tidy Core = {terms: 77, types: 52, coercions: 0}

-- RHS size: {terms: 5, types: 3, coercions: 0}
unending1 :: [Int]
[GblId, Str=DmdType]
unending1 =
  cycle
    @ Int (GHC.Types.: @ Int (GHC.Types.I# 1#) (GHC.Types.[] @ Int))
```

Comment: Did you check the Core? If I had to guess, I'd say that `unendingN` are moved to a local variable or inlined, and then they can be garbage collected. (Even if as a top-level CAFs one would expect them to stay in memory).

Comment: @chi I'm not very experienced at reading core, but I generated it with `-ddump-simpl` and the lists do seem to remain at the top level.

Comment: I now checked the Core, but it's not that. The call from main to the lists is not inlined or made local. Probably global CAFs are now GC'd as András Kovács points out below.

Comment: Readers of this question might find this blog post about memory leaks interesting: http://www.well-typed.com/blog/2016/09/sharing-conduit/ and also the following discussion on Reddit: https://www.reddit.com/r/haskell/comments/550wsj/new_blog_post_sharing_memory_leaks_and_conduit/ https://www.reddit.com/r/haskell/comments/55xk4z/erratum_to_sharing_memory_leaks_and_conduit_and/ It was while trying to reproduce these problems that I came out with my example.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As chi answered, your code runs in constant space because of the definition of `cycle`.

However, it runs in constant space with `ghc -O0` even with `cycle xs = xs ++ cycle xs`, because top-level thunks (constant applicative forms, CAF-s) can be garbage collected. The info tables of closures have "static reference tables", which list static closures such that

- The code of the closure mentions them
- They're either top-level thunks or their code transitively refers to top-level thunks

Documentation [here](https://ghc.haskell.org/trac/ghc/wiki/Commentary/Rts/Storage/GC/CAFs). If top-level thunks can't be reached from GC roots (which include the stacks of thread-state objects, so in our case the closure of `main` under execution), heap objects they point to are discarded.

Comment: I see. If I duplicate the the `print (summator 0 unending1 unending2)` line, should the lists be retained? Because they will be needed for the second print (that will never we reached). If I do that it doesn't exhaust the heap.

Comment: If we define `cycle xs = xs ++ cycle xs` (see chi's answer), duplicated `print` line exhausts the heap , while single `print` line doesn't.

Answer (score 3):

From `GHC.List`:

```
cycle                   :: [a] -> [a]
cycle []                = errorEmptyList "cycle"
cycle xs                = xs' where xs' = xs ++ xs'
```

Note that the recursion does not involve a function call, but a list value `xs'`.

When fully forced, this should be represented in memory as a circular linked-list, with a backward pointer. Only a finite amount of memory is then required.

Try e.g. defining your own `cycle`:

```
cycle' xs = xs ++ cycle' xs
```

since GHC does not do automatic memoization, this should generate an unbounded list in memory.

Indeed, even in GHCi (unoptimized), this stays under 70M on my machine

```
> let list1 :: [Int] ; list1 = cycle [1,2,3]
> list1 !! (4*10^9)
2
```

while this explodes (>1GB):

```
> let list2 :: [Int] ; list2 = cycle' [1,2,3]
> list2 !! (4*10^7)
2
```

Comment: Static object GC doesn't kick in with ghci, but with  `ghc -O0` `cycle'` runs in constant space as well.

Comment: Yes, for the leak to happen in the compiled code, we need to use the modified `cycle'` AND duplicate the `print` statement so the lists are not garbage collected.