# Does Haskell discards intermediary results during lazy evaluation?

Tags: haskell, lazy-evaluation, lazy-sequences

If I define the Fibonacci sequence recursively:

```
fibo_lazy_list = 0 : 1 : zipWith (+) fibo_lazy_list (tail fibo_lazy_list)
```

Then ask for the first element above a given value, say:

```
print $ find (>100) fibo_lazy_list
```

I understand that Haskell evaluates only the elements which are required to get the printed results. But are they all kept in memory until the print ? Since only two elements of the list are required to compute the last one, does Haskell release the left-most elements or does the list keep growing in memory ?

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40562489/why-doesnt-this-haskell-code-exhaust-the-heap

Answer (score 10, accepted):

*It depends*.

This is actually one of the most tricky things to get right for real-world Haskell code: to avoid memory leaks caused by holding on to unnecessary data, that was only supposed to be intermediary but turns out to be actually a dependency to some yet-unevaluated lazy thunk, and therefore can't be garbage-collected.

In your example, the leading elements of `fibo_lazy_list` (BTW, please use `camelCase`, not `underscore_case` in Haskell) will not be garbage-collected as long as `fibo_lazy_list` is refered by something that could still be evaluated. But as soon as it goes out of scope, that isn't possible. So if you write it like this

```
print $ let fibo_lazy_list = 0 : 1 : zipWith (+) fibo_lazy_list (tail fibo_lazy_list)
        in find (>100) fibo_lazy_list
```

then you can be pretty confident that the unused elements *will* be garbage collected, possibly before the one to be printed is even found.

If however `fibo_lazy_list` is defined at the top-level, and is a [CAF](https://wiki.haskell.org/Constant_applicative_form) (as it will be if the type is not polymorphic)

```
fiboLazyList :: [Integer]
fiboLazyList = 0 : 1 : zipWith (+) fiboLazyList (tail fiboLazyList)

main :: IO ()
main = do
   ...
   print $ find (>100) fiboLazyList
   ...
```

then you should better expect all the leading elements to stay in memory even after the `>100` one has been extracted.

Compiler optimisation *may* come in helpful here, so can strictness annotations. But as I said, this is a bit of a pain in Haskell.